# Why is my implementation of fast natural exponentiation slow?

Tags: c++, optimization, floating-point, c++20, exponentiation

I am trying to implement a fast natural exponentiation function. I read the corresponding section in the [pbrt-v4](https://pbr-book.org/4ed/Utilities/Mathematical_Infrastructure#FastExp) book, and wrote this function, which computes `e^x` as `2^(1/ln(2) * x)` by taking the integer and fractional parts `i` and `f` of `1/ln(2) * x`, using a polynomial to approximate `2^f`, then assuming IEEE754 `float32` representation and adding `i` to the exponent.

The main function `fast_exp` is below.

```cpp
inline auto fast_exp(float exponent) {
    auto base_two_exponent = exponent * 1.44269504089f;

    auto exp_integer_part = std::floor(base_two_exponent);
    auto exp_fractional_part = base_two_exponent - exp_integer_part;
    
    /* Use polynomial to approximate 2 ^ exp_fractional_part */
    auto two_to_exp_fractional_part = evaluate_polynomial(
        exp_fractional_part,
        1.f, 0.695556856f, 0.226173572f, 0.0781455737f
    );

    int resulting_exponent = IEEE754::get_exponent(two_to_exp_fractional_part)
                                   + static_cast<int>(exp_integer_part);

    /* If exponent is out of range do clamping */
    if (resulting_exponent < -126) { return 0._; }
    else if (resulting_exponent > 127) { return std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity(); }

    auto bits = IEEE754::float_to_bits(two_to_exp_fractional_part);
    bits &= 0b10000000011111111111111111111111;  /* Zero out exponent bits */
    bits |= (resulting_exponent + (1 << 7) - 1) << 23;  /* Fill in exponent with resulting exponent */
    return IEEE754::bits_to_float(bits);
}
```

For full clarity, the IEEE754 utility functions are defined as follows:

```cpp
namespace IEEE754 {
    constexpr inline auto float_to_bits(float f) { return std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(f); }

    constexpr inline auto bits_to_float(uint32_t bits) { return std::bit_cast<float>(bits); }

    constexpr inline auto get_exponent(float f) { return (float_to_bits(f) >> 23) - ((1 << 7) - 1); }

    constexpr inline auto get_significand(float f) { return float_to_bits(f) & ((1 << 23) - 1); }

    constexpr inline auto get_sign_bit(float f) { return float_to_bits(f) & 0x80000000; }
};
```

and `evaluate_polynomial(x, c0, c1, c2, c3, ...)` uses [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) to evaluate the polynomial with coefficients `ci` as `c0 + c1(x + c2(x + ...`. Note that I use the fused multiply-add function `std::fma`, which is technically only in C++23, but is supported by my compiler.

---

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr inline auto evaluate_polynomial(float x, T constant_term) {
    return constant_term;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr inline auto evaluate_polynomial(float x, T constant_term, Ts... coefficients) {
    return std::fma(x, evaluate_polynomial(x, coefficients...), constant_term);
}
```

Now, I ran the following simple benchmark with both `std::exp` and with `fast_exp`.

```
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    /* Generate 10 million random exponents in the range [-120, 120] */
    std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(-120, 120);

    std::vector<float> nums(10000000);
    for (auto &f : nums) {f = dist(gen);}

    /* Call fast_exp, or std::exp, on all those exponents */
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto sum = 0._f;
    for (auto f : nums) {
        sum += fast_exp(f);  /* Or std::exp(f) */
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << " ms\n";

    if (!sum) {return 1;}  /* Prevent the above loop from being optimized out */
    return 0;
}
```

Using GCC version 11.4.0 and optimization level `-O2`, **`fast_exp` turns out slower than `std::exp`**; 60-65ms vs 45ms. This is contrary to the book's claims, as well as many other online comments I've seen that claim this algorithm works faster than the standard library `std::exp`. **Is there a specific reason why my code is slower here? Have I made a mistake?**

---

**UPDATE:** I found that removing the two `if`-statements reduces the runtime of `fast_exp` by a factor of 2 (by 30ms). However, I don't know how to eliminate these branches, or if there is anything else that can be optimized here.

Comment: The conditionals can be removed with a branchless blend instruction. AFAIK, this is platform dependent and there is no standard way to do that in pure C++ without external libraries (as long as the [SIMD TS](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/simd) is not released as a part of the standard). The usual way to do that in C++ is to use platform-dependent intrinsics or SIMD libraries.

Comment: This kind of implementation is known to be SIMD friendly but may not be faster than the GCC implementation which is AFAIK based on a LUT (not SIMD friendly but possibly faster for scalar when the cache is hot). Note that faster is dependent of the context/usage : an implementation can have a higher latency while having a better throughput.

Comment: GCC is just the compiler, it is not a full C++ implementation, and it needs to be combined with an implementation of the standard C++ library. You did not say what implementation you are using. The library `exp` may be written in assembly and customized for particular hardware. In assembly, it may be using a variety of techniques for manipulating the bits of IEEE-754 representations that are not available in C++, so it will outperform `get_exponent` and such.

Comment: A well-written implementation will also avoid tests such as `resulting_exponent > 127`. Instead, it may simply let a multiplication operation overflow, yielding infinity. (In addition to performance, that is a behavioral improvement over your code, because it correctly generates an overflow exception, whereas your code passively returns ∞ with no indication of overflow.)

Comment: @Christopher Miller Re "Note that I use the fused multiply-add function std::fma, which is technically only in C++23, but is supported by my compiler." Per section 26.8 of the ISO-C++11 standard, `fma()` was included via `cmath` (from ISO-C99); it is listed in table 119 "Header `<cmath>` synopsis"

Comment: @Christopher Miller Have you examined the code emitted for the benchmark? For example, a compiler may vectorize (or use a canned vectorized version of) built-in `exp()` but not a user-supplied `fast_exp()`. Compiler flags, e.g. `-O2` vs `-O3`, or `-march=core-avx2` vs `-march=skylake-avx512` may also influence that.